# How can I make this Ruby block extensible?

Tags: ruby, refactoring, block

I need to adapt the following block to create montages based on `@item.type`. For this to happen, the block contents must be change on a per `@item.type` basis.

```
list = Magick::ImageList.new(@item.images)
montage = list.montage do
  self.geometry = Magick::Geometry.new(130, 194, 10, 5)
  self.geometry = Magick::Geometry.new(4,10)
end
montage.write("name.jpg")
```

Depending on `@item.type` the following methods may or may not be need, and the values supplied will be different: (I may need `self.foo` but not `self.geometry`, for example)

```
self.geometry = Magick::Geometry.new(130, 194, 10, 5)
self.tiles = Magick::Geometry.new(4,10)
```

Short of `if @item.type = 'this' ...` what's the "Ruby Way" to do this?

Answer (score 1):

What about giving the item a method for emitting the type of geometry required?

```
montage = list.montage do
  self.geometry = Magick::Geometry.new(*@item.geometry)
end
```

Then you'd have a method that emits geometry:

```
def geometry
  [ 4, 10 ]
end
```

**Update:** Using a presenter-type class.

```
class Item
  def render_helper
    ItemRenderHelper.new(self)
  end
end

class ItemRenderHelper
  def initialize(item)
    @item = item
  end

  def render(context)
    context.geometry = Magick::Geometry.new(130, 194, 10, 5)
    context.tiles = Magick::Geometry.new(4, 10)
  end
end

class OtherItem
  def render_helper
    OtherItemRenderHelper.new(self)
  end
end

class OtherItemRenderHelper
  def initialize(other_item)
    @other_item = other_item
  end

  def render(context)
    context.geometry = Magick::Geometry.new(...)
    context.tiles = Magick::Geometry.new(...)
    context.other_method(...)
  end
end
```

Then you can apply these:

```
montage = list.montage do
  @item.render_helper.render(self)
end
```

Comment: Good idea, but what if at times `self.geometry` is not needed, but `self.tile` or `self.foo` are?

Comment: Another thing, moving the method to `Item` just moves the problem. I'd still have to use `if` or `case` in `Item` to determine what to send back.

Comment: @dee: instead of `if` use `case when` - it's cleaner :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I was hoping I would avoid using conditionals. Can't I move this into a class? If so, can you guide me as to what the class might look like? I have many other params, so I don't think conditionals will cut it.

Comment: @dee: remember, code should be easy to read, that's most important.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev About 4 extra params, but they're unpredictable.

Comment: Using `case` is a great place to start, but differentiating on object type is usually a sign you need to think about proper object-oriented design patterns. Each `item` should probably have some kind of renderer class (a form of the presenter pattern) that takes care of making `Magick` calls. Then the `montage` part doesn't need to concern itself with the details of how each item is to be rendered, and each item doesn't need to concern itself with the details of `Magick`, instead delegating to the helper class.